# Sqlalchemy gives 'Function sequence error (0) (SQLFetch)')

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am connecting to sql database and it used to work fine just last month.
However the job produced an error and I cannot figure out what does it want?

```
from statistics import variance
from tkinter import Variable
import pandas as pd
import shutil
import os
import sqlalchemy as sa
import openpyxl


import urllib
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
                                  "SERVER=101010;"
                                  "DATABASE=MyDb;"
                                  "UID=MyUid;"
                                  "PWD=1234")



engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params))


# read .sql file
sql01 = open('SP_ParamsTest.sql', 'r') 
sqlFile = sql01.read()
sql01.close()

# this lines generates an error:
df_params = pd.read_sql(sqlFile, con=engine)
```

**full error message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MyPath\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\cursor.py", line 977, in fetchall
    rows = dbapi_cursor.fetchall()
pyodbc.Error: ('HY010', '[HY010] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Function sequence error (0) (SQLFetch)')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    rows = self._fetchall_impl()
  File "C:\Users\MyPath\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\cursor.py", line 1805, in _fetchall_impl
    return self.cursor_strategy.fetchall(self, self.cursor)
  File "C:\Users\MyPath\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\cursor.py", line 981, in fetchall
    self.handle_exception(result, dbapi_cursor, e)
  File "C:\Users\MyPath\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\cursor.py", line 941, in handle_exception
    result.connection._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "C:\MyPath\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2124, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\MyPath\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\MyPath\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\cursor.py", line 977, in fetchall
    rows = dbapi_cursor.fetchall()
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY010', '[HY010] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Function sequence error (0) (SQLFetch)')
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/dbapi)
```

Comment: Can you add the query from `SP_ParamsTest.sql`?

Comment: Barmar, I think you got it. In my SP_ParamsTest.sql the first line of code was `drop table if exists ##params`. I took it off and it works now. Please post the answer

Answer (score 1):

I see you've got this working already, but there is another problem I want to mention since sqlalchemy has been updated.

Since sqlalchemy 2.0 passing a string to Connection.execute() has been removed, we need to use the text() construct, or the Connection.exec_driver_sql() method to use a SQL string

What this means is simply to use:

```
from sqlalchemy import text
...
df_params = pd.read_sql(text(sqlFile), con=engine)
```

With this text() function you can also put the sql parameters into the SQL query like this (Tables from AX 2012 database):

```
SELECT ITEMID
FROM INVENTTABLE
WHERE ITEMID = :id
```

And use those parameters safely from the program with

```
df_params = pd.read_sql(text(sqlFile), con=engine, params= {'id': '100001'})
```